# Shortest journey time from source to destination

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Consider a list of stations, say 10 stations, 'A' to 'J', connected by trains running between them.

> In terms of graph, consider the stations (Vertices) and trains running
>   between them (Edges) to form a connected graph but not complete, i.e.
>   each station is reachable from any station either directly or via
>   other stations by making hops. Most importantly, these hops includes
>   waits between arrival and next departure. Quite understandably, the
>   journey time between two connected stations is independent. However,
>   the waiting time to next departure depends where you arrived from.
>
> **NOTE:** I mention graph only to aid understanding. One could think beyond it.

**Problem:** Given any two stations and start time from the initial station, how to find shortest time to the destination, counting the waiting time between arrival and departure in cases of hops? And what DS will be used for the same? Assume that if two stations are connected by a train, then only-and-only one train is running between them.

Comment: Only to illustrate further, assume a train between 'C' and 'D'. Also Assume that you can arrive at 'C' from either 'A' or 'B'. The waiting time at station 'C', for train to 'D', thus depends if you arrived at 'C' from 'A' or 'B'. However, the journey time from 'C' to 'D' is same irrespective of how and when you arrived at 'C'.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm => assuming, time for going one station to another is not equal.

Comment: @MukitChowdhury - Dijkstra is not enough here, because of these "hops".

Comment: @MukitChowdhury: This is not routine Dijkstra's Shortest-Path. If vertices denote stations and edges denote journey time, how does one account for the waiting time?

Comment: Do only the hops have a waiting time for the next departure, or do we have waiting times for travelling between the edges as well? Is waiting time the same for each possible hop from a vertex or can it differ for hops having different destinations?

Comment: @Ilim: Every train has a specified departure and arrival time. Assume there are no delays and all trains are running on schedule.

Comment: @Ilim: Obviously waiting times differ. As the question mentions that Journey time is independent but waiting time is dependent. Just as in real life.

Comment: @SubhajitKundu Are there any restrictions as to where one may hop, or can a passenger, if costs deem useful, hop from A to C even though A->B->C exists?

Comment: This is not the a usual shortest path computation at all, if "*Every train has a specified departure and arrival time*" is indeed true. If that is true, then journey time is a function of **start time** as well as origin+destination!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO Dijkstra should be enough after all.

If you run Dijkstra from node "A", it finds shortest path to all other nodes.

Even when we have "hops", the worst case is that you get to some station earlier and then you have to wait to the same train as if you get there later with some other route.

The only difference is, that you count price as "time of waiting + time of travel" instead of only "time of travel"

This behaviour is caused by trains having real "arrival/departure".

If each route for every A2 node in every node combination A1 -> A2 -> A3 get random penalization for going from A1 to A3 through A2, then it would be unpredictable I think.

Comment: Nope! Dijkstra is not the answer.

Consider 'A', 'B' and 'J' with source = 'A' and dest = 'J'. Consider 'A' is connected to 'J' by a train at Morning 6 and it takes 2 hours. Consider 'A' is connected to 'B' by a train at 12 in the noon and it takes 3 hrs and 'B' is connected to 'J' at 6 in the evening and it takes 3 hours again. If the traveller starts at 5 in the morning, then 'A' to 'J' is shortest. However, if the traveller starts at 10 AM, then he/she can reach 'J' via 'B' and reach destination in 11 hours. As we wish to minimize total time thus this route is shortest for him/her.

Comment: @SubhajitKundu - this is what modified Dijkstra would solve. The "price" is total ammount of hours - the waiting AND the traveling time. If you start at 10 AM, then the shortest path is A -> B, which is "2 hours waiting + 3 hours traveling = 5 hours", so it will be first node opened. Then you measure "total ammount" of hours again for B -> J, which will cost less than A -> J.

Comment: @SubhajitKundu - the only difference is, that you have to count the price, every time you come somewhere as well as carring exact time of arrival. Only little more difficult, but no changes in dijksra itself at all.